# query printing extra table row causing issue with import into spreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, google-sheets

I have the following simple query:

```
Select products_id, products_status from products order by products_id
```

It outputs a table like this:

| products_id | Products_status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 |

Here is my Php which is echoing the table into Html so that I can import it into an excel spreadsheet:

```
      <table>
<?php

$listing_sql = "Select products_id, products_status from products order by products_id";
$status_query = tep_db_query($listing_sql);

while ($statusproduct = tep_db_fetch_array($status_query)) {
    if (tep_not_null($statusproduct['products_id'])) {
        if (tep_not_null($statusproduct['products_id'])) {

            echo "<tr><td>" . $statusproduct['products_id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $statusproduct['products_status'] . "</td><tr />";

        }
    }
}

?>
      </table>
```

The issue is this is for some reason when looking at the html in developer tools in chrome I see the html like so:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
    <tr />
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
    <tr />
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
    <tr />
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1</td>
    <tr />
    <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Note the extra table row being echoed.

The strange this is when I view source in chrome it does not have that extra table row.

The issue is, when using IMPORTHTML in sheets it is skipping a row.

Is there a reason that this is happening?

Comment: MIght be your incorrect closing `<tr>` tag. You have `<tr />` but should be `</tr>`

Comment: Gah that was it so dumb and I looked at it 100 times. THank you!